# UICollectionView how to add margin to active cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a simple `UICollectionView`. And I need to show user active cell like this:
[image]

Active cell in middle.

How I can do this?

Comment: You can set the `sectionInset` property of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object

Comment: But sectionInset work for all cell in section?

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood, I thought the active cell is always in the middle. Otherwise, update `cell.layer.frame.y` in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and reset in `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` methods

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to change the appearance of a selected cell:

You should implement UICollectionViewDelegate and implement all necessary methods, i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

and

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
```

didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

and change the appearance. How you do it for your cell depends on your app, i.e.  change the alignment of a bottom constraint within the cells view hierarchy or change the relative y-position of an inner view.

Just make sure, that you really you keep track about your custom selection as you need to reset (or set) it in

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

as cells are reused.

Also have a look at [Apple Dokumentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW8)